# Why does not my application change language?

Tags: android

In an activity I did the following to change the language of the app:

```
    private void changeLanguage(String stringLanguage){
        Locale locale = new Locale(stringLanguage);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        Intent refresh = new Intent(ActLanguage.this, ActLanguage.class);
        startActivity(refresh);
        finish();
    }
```

But only that activity changes language, all the other activities that the project contains remain in the original language.

Any suggestions or comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some workaround for changing app language would be.

- Set language once when user change. and change language automatically when user start app next time.
- You can save user preferred language and set next time when app opens.

This does not work because you did not call `onConfigurationChanged()`.

This would be your application class. You can change language by calling method.

```
AppContext.getInstance().changeLanguage("en");
Intent refresh = new Intent(ActLanguage.this, ActLanguage.class);
finish();        
startActivity(refresh);
```

and `AppContext.java` class

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import java.util.Locale;


public class AppContext extends Application {
    public static final String PREFERENCE = "NYPrefsFile";
    public static final String KEY_LANG = "LANG";
    private static AppContext mApp = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mApp = this;
        setLanguage();
        sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE, 0);
    }

    public synchronized static AppContext getInstance() {
        return mApp;
    }

    public void setLanguage() {
        String lang = getStringData(KEY_LANG);
        changeLanguage(lang);
    }

    public String getCurrentLanguage() {
        if (config == null)
            config = getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        return config.locale.getLanguage();
    }

    Configuration config;

    public void changeLanguage(String lang) {
        if (config == null)
            config = getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        config.locale = locale;
        getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        setStringData(KEY_LANG, lang);
        onConfigurationChanged(config);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private SharedPreferences sp;

    public String getStringData(String pKey) {
        return sp.getString(pKey, "");
    }

    public void setStringData(String pKey, String pData) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putString(pKey, pData);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:name=".AppContext"
```

**Update:**

You will start your home activity with clearing back-stack to load all activities with new language.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
finish(); // call this to finish the current activity
```

Comment: I have done it this way and it doesn't work:

private void cambiarIdiomaAplicacion(String cadenaIdioma){
        Locale locale = new Locale(cadenaIdioma);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        onConfigurationChanged(config);
    
        Intent refresh = new Intent(ActIdioma.this, ActIdioma.class);
        startActivity(refresh);
        finish();
    }

Comment: @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

Comment: Have you double check your language string xml exist at right place.

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758

Comment: Yes, The language string xml is in its correct place, that's why in ActLanguage activity it changes all the TextView it contains. But as I mentioned before only that activity is the one that changes, if I return to others, they remain in the language by default of the phone.

Comment: I got that. I faced this too, you have to load your activity again with clearing stack to make changes in all activities.

Answer (score 0):

Do if from the Application context and not from the Activity context. Use getApplicationContext() .

Also use createConfigurationContext from API 25 as updateConfiguration is deprecated .

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```js
  Intent refresh = new Intent(ActIdioma.this, ActMAINACTIVITY.class);
        refresh.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(refresh);
finish();
```

Calling the main activity, all the others change language.